# LinkedIn Follow Company and Share Plugin buttons language issue in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, button, plugins, share, linkedin-api

I created a Linkedin Follow Company button here: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company.

However, when I add it to my WordPress site, it shows up in English, regardless of what language I set. The code contains `lang: da_DK` to show the button in Danish, but it's still displayed in English.

When I test it outside of WordPress, it shows up in the right language, which suggests it's a WordPress issue, but WP can display buttons from Facebook and Twitter in the right language, which suggests it's a LinkedIn issue.

How can I make the button appear in Danish on my WordPress site?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsite-follow-us-badges/screenshots/

It provide option to select language also.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My webpage had the **Company Profile** plugin in header, and the **Follow Company** plugin in footer. I was wrongly including the `platform.linkedin.com/in.js` script twice, the first occurence did not include the `lang` parameter.

Be sure to include `platform.linkedin.com/in.js` once in HTML code with the right `lang: da_DK` param value.